# Is there a way to export setState outside stateless components in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, stateless

**Consider this example**

```
export function InsideHoc(props){
   const [A, setA] = useState(false);

   return({if(A) && (<h1>Print something</h1>)});
}
```

**In another file**

```
import {A, setA} from './inside-file';

function ToggleFromOutside(){
   return(<p onClick={setA(!A)}>Verify</p>);
}
```

Can setA be exposed outside so that the state of this component be changed from outside? I know this can be done through redux. But without using this, is there a way to change the state of one component?

**Structure is like this**

```
import {withCreateHOC} from './external';
import childComponent from './child';


class A extends React.Component {
   render(){
      <Another menus={(item) => <MenuItems object={item} />}
       />
   }
}

 export default withCreateHOC(A, {custom: childComponent, title: 'Add'});
```

//withCreateHOC renders modal here as well as it has a button to toggle the state. Same state should be used from below function

```
function MenuItems(){
   return(<button onClick={displayModal}>)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

You can [lift the state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) in that case. This works good if you don't need to pass down the setState to far down the tree.

If you don't want to pass the setState function all the way down the React element tree, you will need to use [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), redux or some other state handling.

### Example state lift

```
export function Parent(){
   const [message, setMessage] = useState("Hello World");

   return (
     <>
      <Child1 message={message} />
      <Child2 changeMessage={setMessage} />
     </>

   );
}

// Can be in other file
function Child1(props){
   return(<p>{props.message}</p>);
}

// Can be in other file
function Child2(props){

   return(
     <a onClick={() => props.changeMessage("Changed")}>  
       I can change things in other components.
     </a>
   );
}
```

### Example of React tree with shared context/redux

```
<WithRedux>
  <App>
    <Navigation />
    <Modal />
    <PageRenderer />
    <SomeList>
      <ListItem />
      <ListItem />
    </Somelist>
  </App>
<WithRedux>
```

All the children of the WithRedux component can access the state and modify it.
(PS: You can wrap the App with the HOC withRedux etc, this example is just for visualization)

Comment: wonderful attempt, but that child1 and child2 cant be inside Parent component in my case :) They are in different files. I am just trying to access the state of one component in another without parent, child relationships and not using redux. Attempting via context is probably the solution which i am looking at to accept the answer :)

Comment: How would your two components be structured, do they not have a common parent ever? In that case, context can't help either. Since the context provider needs to be the parent of both components.

Comment: I think of only redux as a solution to my problem

Comment: Redux also needs a common parent to wrap your store in. All the solutions require this. The only difference is how deep your render tree is and context and redux helps you avoid passing down state, functions all the way down.

Comment: So can redux be wrapped to class A of HOC here?

Comment: Yes, you can, but the component that is reading the state or wants to perform an action also needs to be a child of the HOC then.

Comment: I feel of wrapping menuitems component and withcreateHoc component and class A all three, i am not sure how to structure this...

Comment: Updated the answer, might give some clarity.